# What does this syntax mean (<T=Self>) and when to use it?

Tags: generics, rust

I sometimes see things like `<T=Self>` or `T=()` in generic structs/traits. I suspect that this has something to do with default types for the generic type `T`. I couldn't find any documentation though.

My questions are:

- What does it really mean?
- What variations are possible (maybe something crazy like `<T=Self: 'static`>)?
- when is it useful (examples)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This syntax can be used in two situations: default type parameters, and associated types. To see the difference and le use, lets have a look at the `Add` trait, used to define the `+` operator:

```
pub trait Add<RHS = Self> {
    type Output;
    fn add(self, rhs: RHS) -> Self::Output;
}
```

## Default type parameters

Here, the type parameter `RHS` has a default value: `Self`. That means that, whenever I use this trait, the value of this type parameter will default to `Self` if I omit it. For example:

```
impl Add for Foo { /* ... */ }
```

is the same as

```
impl Add<Foo> for Foo { /* ... */ }
```

likewise,

```
fn foo<T>(t: T) where T: Add { /* ... */ }
```

is the same as

```
fn foo<T>(t: T) where T: Add<T> { /* ... */ }
```

## Associated types

The trait `Add` also has an associated type : `Output`. This type is chosen by the implementation of the trait.

The reason behind this is that it would not make any sense to implement `Add` with different output types while the input types are the same: once `Self` and `RHS` are known, the `Output` type cannot be chosen.

This construct is also used for iterators for example, when you iterate over a container, you do not get to choose the type of the values generated by the iterator: it is thus an associated type.

It is possible to select a value for an associated type in `where` clauses, by using this `Foo = Bar` syntax. For example:

```
fn foo<I>(i: I) where I: Iterator<Item=u8> { /* ... */ }
```

this function can work on any iterator yielding `u8` values.

## To sum up

The syntax `Foo=Bar` used in the definition of a generic construct allows you to set a default value for a type parameter, and used in `where` clauses it allows you to match on the value of an associated type.

There are no possible variations like `Foo = Bar : Baz` or things like that.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

This syntax is used together with [associated types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/associated-types.html). Sometimes you want to avoid specifying the variables each time and want them to be specified by the type, therefore you have the syntax as follows:

```
trait Operation {
    type Input: Display;
    type Output: Display;

    fn do_it(&self, g: Self::Input) -> Self::Output;
}
```

as opposed to

```
trait Operation<T: Display, V: Display> {    
    fn do_it(&self, g: T) -> V;
}
```

In this case when you declare a function which uses `Operation` you can simply write `fn take_operation<O: Operation>(operation: O, input: O::Input) -> O::Output` instead of `fn take_operation<T: Display, V: Display, O: Operation<T, V>>(operation: O, input: T) -> V`.

In some cases you want to limit the range of types you accept, though. Let's take, for example, the case when you want to limit the types of input to `u32`. Normally you would write `fn take_operation<V: Display, O: Operation<u32, V>>(operation: O, input: u32) -> V`. With the associated types, however, you will specify the constraint differently: `fn take_operation<O: Operation<Input=u32>>(operation: O, input: u32) -> O::Output`.